# Email Google Form Responses Only When a Work Order Number is added to the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, eventtrigger

I want to email form responses to a help desk email once they are "approved" and a "work order #" is assigned, meaning I open the spreadsheet and assign initials to the approved column and assign a work order number to the new work order column. I've modified many scripts to try to achieve this. I do not want the responses sent immediately upon form submission, as they need at least a work order attached. Below is the script I've attempted to modify (shown below without any modification). It works fine IF I want the form submissions to go directly to the email when a user hits submit. Again, I need them emailed ONLY when a work order is attached to the respective line item in the spreadsheet.

```
function nl2br_(input_string){
  return input_string.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'<br />');
}

function RequestNWOMailer(e) {
  try {
    var recipient = 'test-area@efriends44221.org';
    var timestamp = e.values[0];
    var name = e.values[1];
    var contactmethod = e.values[2];
    var emailphone = e.values[3];
    var building = e.values[4];
    var room = e.values[5];
    var reason = e.values[6];
    var description = e.values[7];
    var approval = e.values[8];
    var nwo = e.values[9];
    var subject = building+' <'+reason+'> <'+name+'>';
    var body = name+' <'+emailphone+'> sent the following: '+description;
    var bodyHTML = '\
        <p>NWO #: '+nwo+'</p>\
        <p>'+name+' sent the following: </p>\
        <p>Contact Method: '+contactmethod+'</p>\
        <p>Email of Phone#: '+emailphone+'</p>\
        <p>Building: '+building+'</p>\
        <p>Room #: '+room+'</p>\
        <p>Reason for NWO: '+reason+'</p>\
        <p>Description: '+nl2br_(description)+'</p>';
    var advancedArgs = {htmlBody:bodyHTML , replyTo:emailphone};
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, advancedArgs);
  } catch(e){MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, "Error - Request for New Work Order Form", e.message);
  }
}
```